# How to not "play catch up" on missed messages when subscribing to a channel using the PubNub iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I'm using the [PubNub iOS SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/api-reference-sdk-v4) and am unsubscribing to a channel and then shortly after (1-3 minutes) am re-subscribing to it.

I'm noticing that when subscribing to a channel, PubNub will send all messages that its missed since unsubscribing from that channel (with limitations). I saw in [this blog post](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/328/should-i-use-the-restore-setting) and [this one](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/413/how-do-you-retain-received-messages-upon-page-reload) that this can done in the JavaScript SDK via using `restore: true` in the call to subscribe to the channel.

I tried doing the opposite - using `restore: false` - when subscribing:

```
NSString *channelName = @"myChannelName";
NSDictionary *state = @{channelName: @{@"restore": @(NO)}};

[self.client subscribeToChannels:@[channelName]
                    withPresence:YES
                     clientState:state];
```

However, this did not work, and all missed messages were received directly after subscribing.

Is there any way to **not** receive all missed messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting about this issue. We examined code responsible for unsubscription and found why it may happen for you. Release has been pushed and available on GitHub and CocoaPods (**v4.2.3**) which should address your issue.

Comment: The newest release (v4.2.3) fixes this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the PubNub GitHub](https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c), this is suppressed by setting `restoreSubscription` in your `PNConfiguration` to `NO`.

You have to define your `PNConfiguration` first:

```
    @property(nonatomic, strong) PNConfiguration *myConfig;
```

And then PubNub gives you the option as follows:

```
    self.myConfig.restoreSubscription = NO;
```

And then on your `PubNub`, set your configuration

```
    [PubNub setConfiguration:self.myConfig];
```

More information on Configuration is under the **Configuration** section of the PubNub link above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It looks `restoreSubscription` will automatically restore the subscription to the previously subscribed live channel (and play catch-up) if the connection is lost. I *do* want this feature. However what I don't want is when creating a new subscription manually (via  `-[PubNub subscribeToChannels:*]`) to play catch-up on all missed messages.

Comment: @JoshSklar there was issue for case when client unsubscribed from all channels and then restored by request subscription on them (mentioned in separate response). Normal behaviour is what _-subscribeToChannels:_ is additive and if client already subscribed to some channels, it will keep using timestamp which has been received earlier with channels on which you subscribe now (again, this is when not affected by bug which we addressed for you and pushed in new release).